# Android GPS chip manufacturer

Tags: android, gps

Is there a way to obtain the manufacturer of the GPS chip of an Android device?

I can't find it anywhere...

Comment: You'll probably have better luck on Android StackExchange http://android.stackexchange.com/ Stack Overflow questions are supposed to generally relate to programming in some way. However I am not sure the information you're looking for is public.

Answer (score 3):

Android application is designed to run on any hardware that support Android framework, then 
Hardware definition is not really part of the android framework ... 
 ... In pure Linux with enough priviledge, surely yes, there is way to introspect hardware/device/driver
... In Pure android way (over dalvik ) I guess there is no way to know it ..

Then If you need for an application to know what is the GPS or other component stuff, make and fill a database with all android models and its hardware specification then by the "model number" (retrieve-able from android see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) you may query the good information..

Comment: Oh I should have added, I meant if it was in the API to obtain manufacturer details programmatically.
Thanks anyway